# Sum Time (HH:MM) in RDLC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, rdlc

I have and RDLC report an I need to get the sum of the fild "Time". I save it in the database with varchar type with the format "hh:mm".
[image]

I get this with the formula:

```
=(Sum(System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HorasEfectivas.Value).Hours))
&":"&
Sum(System.TimeSpan.Parse(Fields!HorasEfectivas.Value).Minutes))
```

The problem here is the sum of the minutes. 140 minutes shoul be transformed in hours!
How can I get this?
Regards

Comment: "I save it in the database with varchar type with the format "hh:mm"" Why? That's fundamentally inimical to numeric operations. Why not just save the number of minutes? Or store a `TimeSpan` directly in the database? You can always format that as hh:mm in the app... You should usually try to store the data in a form which is a "native" representation of the data, rather than a textual representation of a non-textual type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using TimeSpan e.g.

```
      var time1 = new TimeSpan(0,2,02,0);
      var time2 = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 02, 0);

      var totalHours = time1 + time2;
```